# Error opening excel generated with EPPlus in medium trust environment

Tags: c#, export-to-excel, epplus

I have searched high and low and find similar questions all with similar answers and none seem to solve my problem. My ultimate goal is to allow the user to save a datatable to an excel document which opens (not saves) in excel and they can choose to save it if they wish. This is to be done with the click of a button on a webpage written in c#.

There's tons of examples on how to do this, in many different ways, many of which seem quite straightforward - I just can't seem to find a way that completely works in the environment I am in (medium trust production environment and this cannot be altered).

Essentially, when a button is clicked on the webpage, my code creates an excel file using EPPlus:

```
ExcelPackage p = new ExcelPackage();
p.Workbook.Worksheets.Add(worksheetname);
ExcelWorksheet workSheet = p.Workbook.Worksheets[1];
workSheet.Cells[1,1].LoadFromDataTable(dt, true);
var range = workSheet.Cells[1,1,dt.Rows.Count,dt.Columns.Count];
var table = workSheet.Tables.Add(range, "results");
table.ShowTotal = false;
table.TableStyle = TableStyles.Medium4;
workSheet.Cells.AutoFitColumns();
workSheet.Cells.Style.HorizontalAlignment = ExcelHorizontalAlignment.Left;
workSheet.View.ShowGridLines = false;
Response.Clear();
Response.ClearHeaders();
Response.BinaryWrite(p.GetAsByteArray());
//Also tried this instead of above line with same error: p.SaveAs(Response.OutputStream);
Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;  filename=" + filename + ".xlsx");
Response.End();
```

This code seems straightforward, and works locally from my machine. I click the button, then receive a prompt to Save or Open. I choose Open, and the file opens in Excel, which is exactly what my end users want. I then copy the website out to our dev web server(full trust) and it still works great. Then I copy to our staging environment which is medium trust, not full trust and get the following error: `System.Security.SecurityException Exception Message: Request for the permission of type 'System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed.`

I am not trying to save a file, just simply display for the end user to be able to open it in Excel. They can then choose to Save-As from Excel app if they wish.

Doing this with Excel interop is straightforward and I got it working locally as well, but without Excel on the server, I don't believe this is a viable option. Hence my decision to try EPPlus, which seemed like the answer until it wouldn't work in our staging environment. The only difference I can think of is that our staging environment is medium trust and the development environment is full trust. I need a solution that works in medium trust, but without the errors of my other option I tried below using html.

I used to do this as html and open with the following code, but since it isn't a true excel file, when the user selects open, they always got the error:  "The file format and extension don't match. The file could be corrupted or unsafe. Unless you trust its source, don't open it. Do you want to open it anyway?". They could just hit yes and most of the time the file would open and behave just fine, other times it will simply say "Unable to read file" and they would have to re-click the button - they have requested this error go away. Here is how I used to do it (and again, this worked most the time, and works just fine in our medium trust environment, but has that pesky error). This is why I decided to go the route of creating a 'true' excel file-to avoid this error.

```
System.IO.StringWriter tw = new System.IO.StringWriter();
System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter hw = new System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter(tw);
DataGrid dgGrid = new DataGrid();
dgGrid.DataSource = dt;
dgGrid.DataBind();
dgGrid.RenderControl(hw);
Response.Clear();
Response.ClearContent();
Response.ClearHeaders();
Response.Buffer = true;
Response.Expires = 0;
Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
//Also tried these two ways to see if the "file format and extension don't match" error go away-it didn't
//also tried sending in filename with .xls and .xlsx extension with same results
//Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
//Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + filename);
this.EnableViewState = false;
Response.Write(tw.ToString());
Response.Flush();
Response.Clear();
Response.End();
```

Any suggestions would be great! Also, if there is another open source tool which may do the job, that would be good too. I cannot use any and all open source options, but if someone has a suggestion on another tool that would work in medium trust, I can see if it's in my company's approved list.

Comment: Unlikely, but check this just in case http://ad-thomas.blogspot.com/2013/09/systemsecuritysecurityexception-request.html

Comment: Also does the step "populate worksheet" involve any file IO? Perhaps you are reading something from the file system to populate the data?

Comment: Eric, the link you provided discusses giving the dll additional rights on the server, which is not an option in my company's environment.

Comment: Here is the code I originally took out for populating the worksheet. It does not do any file IO. I simply take a datatable populated with data and transfer it to the worksheet:

Comment: @EricJ. Sorry, I cannot figure out how to get my code to show up correctly in the comments, so I modified my original post

Comment: It is best to update your post.

Comment: Hi @ReneC, did you ever get EPPlus working in a medium trust environment??  I've been trying to sort this out for the last 4 hours and at 1am, I'm now losing the will to be developer anymore.. well until I get some sleep anyway.

Comment: Hi @Ads, discovered the EPPlus dll creates a temporary file as it is creating the excel, and I couldn't find a way to prevent it. This will not work if your server environment doesn't allow you to create temporary files on the server (as is the case with our environment). A co-worker modified the source and recompiled the DLL and it now works great, even with large recordsets (40+k records with 20+ columns), in our medium trust environment. I am waiting to hear back what modification they made and will add a new comment.

Comment: Wow... Thanks @ReneC, I'll have to take a closer look at this.  Thank for the update.  I'm keen to hear what your colleague did to make it work as this is still an issue for me.

Comment: @ReneC, I got dragged off this for the last few days, did you manage to find that code change??

Comment: @Ads see Kirk's answer below.  He is the one who modified the code in our group and explained where the issues are. You need to pull the source code from their website and change in the code where it uses System.IO.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that EPPlus is using features from System.IO even when using the constructors that take a memory stream. That particular library needs full trust, so it will not run in a medium trust environment. Have a look at the following two files:

http://epplus.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#EPPlus/Packaging/ZipPackage.cs

```
string name = Path.GetFileName(p.Key);
string extension = Path.GetExtension(p.Key);
```

http://epplus.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#EPPlus/Packaging/ZipPackagePart.cs

```
internal void WriteZip(ZipOutputStream os)
{
    ...code...
    if (_rels.Count > 0)
    {
        string f = Uri.OriginalString;
        var name = Path.GetFileName(f);
        _rels.WriteZip(os, (string.Format("{0}_rels/{1}.rels", f.Substring(0, f.Length - name.Length), name)));
    }
    ...code...
}
```

Both of those sections use the Path class from System.IO to perform some basic tasks.

ZipPackage.cs solution:

```
var parts = p.Key.Split('/');
var name = parts[parts.Length - 1];
parts = name.Split('.');
var extension = "." + parts[parts.Length - 1];
```

ZipPackagePart.cs solution:

```
internal void WriteZip(ZipOutputStream os)
{
    ...code...
    if (_rels.Count > 0)
    {
        string f = Uri.OriginalString;
        var parts = f.Split('/');
        var name = parts[parts.Length - 1];
        _rels.WriteZip(os, (string.Format("{0}_rels/{1}.rels", f.Substring(0, f.Length - name.Length), name)));
    }
    ...code...
}
```

There may be other places where this issue presents itself, but this should give you an idea of what you need to look for and change after pulling the source code in to your solution. Best of luck!

Comment: thanks for the info, but I still don't really know which bits to change to get this to work, so I ended up going with another package that does work in Medium Trust out of the box, NPOI.  Works almost the same as EPPlus, but not quite as elegantly, but hey, it works without modifying source code.  Maybe I'll have another crack later on if I'm really bothered by not using EPPlus.